# How to get minutes difference between two TIME type attributes in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two TIME attributes and I want to know their difference in minutes, for example:

- time1 = 08:30:00
- time2 = 17:00:00

the difference in minutes is 510 minutes, how can I do this in mysql?

SOLUTION:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CONCAT('0000-01-01 ', time1),CONCAT('0000-01-01 ', time2));
```

Comment: This is not how time works, though. It depends on what day this is on, and in what time zone. Can you work with two `DATETIME` values instead?

Comment: I know you can try this: `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '0000-01-01 08:30:00', '0000-01-01 17:00:00');` but you need to add date to make it working.

Comment: @tadman no, I can't